# initctl reload-configuration command not found

Tags: 15.10, upstart, tomcat

Trying to follow the tomcat installation steps listed [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04)
But cant past this step

```
$ sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

getting the following

```
sudo: initctl: command not found
```

I'm not able to find `initctl` in `/sbin` dir

Ubuntu 15.10 moved away from `upstart`, is that the reason? If so, what is the equivalent of the above the command?

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload`, but I doubt it will help you if you configured it for Upstart.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to install it using `apt-install upstart`:

Try the command `initctl` and you will se the next output, then use the command above:

```
root@ip-XXXXXX:/opt/tomcat# initctl
The program 'initctl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install upstart
```

Command to install it:

```
root@ip-172-31-61-112:/opt/tomcat# apt install upstart
```

#### Possible issue

If you see an output like next:

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be a late answer, but here is a guide to install Tomcat8 on ubuntu 15,04: 
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-15-04-server.html

I checked and for me it seems to work...